# Running android image directly on a VPS

Tags: virtualization, vps, android

I have a VPS server which uses KVM . I can run android using a emulator but I want to run androidx86 directly on the VPS and not through emulation. Is thi possible ?

Comment: If you have a VPS SERVER, then yes.  Just follow the instructions right on the [android x86 website](https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/qemu.html).  If you simply have a VPS as a customer on someone else's server and do not have admin access to the server the VPS is running on, then no.  Not without your provider's help.  This is a question you should ask your provider first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will be possible. Just use Android x86 image to boot the kvm.